# My Notebook with Ubuntu 18.04 freezes after resuming from suspend. How to debug?

Tags: suspend, 18.04, freeze

My Notebook with Ubuntu 18.04 freezes after resuming from suspend. It shows a weird pattern on the screen:

[image]

No mouse pointer visible. No keys have any effect. <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>? doesn't work either.

Before the upgrade to 18.04 suspend and resume worked fine.

My notebook is a `DELL PRECISION M4800`. Config-About shows the following graphics: `Quadro K2100M/PCIe/SSE2`.

How to debug this problem?

Comment: Can you open tty by hitting `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Fx` ? Replace `x` with numbers (that is, F3 - F6)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved after running the following command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```